# How to cluster the CEP rule engine in Drools 6.2.0.Final

Tags: drools, high-availability, complex-event-processing

My system is using Drools to do transaction control,the number of transactions every day will be very large.

The engine event processing mode is "Stream",and I have almost 100 rules,most of them usually need to use Accumulate() & Sliding Time Windows function.

Now the engine only deployed on a single server.I want to cluster the CEP engine to ensure the high availability server,but I can't find in the drools-docs to achieve,so please give me some advice,thank you!

Comment: afaik, there is no clustering for Drools and the high availability can only be achieve non-clustered with a stateful knowledge session which is generally painfully slow and large.

Comment: Thanks to @user650839,u r right I look for a long time didn't find a way to solve this

Comment: You can distribute the workload if events of different event sources (e.g. account) need not be correlated with each other.

Comment: Thanks to @laune ,distribute the wrokload is under consideration now,but we have some rules need the whole event data,so there are some problems to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Use persistence may help you. Please find it in "[4.2.4.9. Persistence and Transactions](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch04.html#KIERunningSection) "

In this section, it says that your stateful session could be persisted to database. And then, others could load your session from database. So, if your database is HA, I believe the whole solution is HA.